# SQL: View with Filter inside or View with Filter on Select

Tags: sql

I have been working on a database that uses a lot of views and the table records are only upto 1 million rows but it has been a pain waiting for my queries to show up.

I wanted to duplicate the View and put a "WHERE CLAUSE" inside. Now to my question:

Is it faster to put a where clause inside a view. For example I would put all customer type = 'BIZ'.

or Would it be the same if I just use the View "SELECT * FROM VIEW_CUSTOMER WHERE type = 'BIZ'"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Adding another view with your filter will not help your performance. You should bring your concerns to your DBA. If you don't have a DBA... then you'll have to find a knowledgeable developer to help troubleshoot your query performance.

Comment: I am not  adding another view. I plan to create a view. to make my question short. Will there be a speed difference when I put a where clause inside the view versus selecting the view and putting a where clause.

Comment: No, there will be no difference in performance. You can test this out by viewing the execution plan

Answer (score 1):

With help this script possible create view with your where clause

```
DECLARE @pref nvarchar(10) = '_type$biz',
        @where_clause nvarchar(max) = 'WHERE 1 = 1',
        @dsql nvarchar(max) = ''
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.#tmp 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn,
       'CREATE VIEW ' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) + @pref
       + ' AS SELECT * FROM ' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) + ' ' + @where_clause AS def
INTO dbo.#tmp       
FROM sys.sql_modules m JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'V'

DECLARE @i int = (SELECT MIN(rn) FROM dbo.#tmp)

WHILE (@i IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT @dsql = def FROM dbo.#tmp WHERE rn = @i
  EXEC sp_executesql @dsql
  SELECT @i = MIN(rn) FROM dbo.#tmp WHERE rn > @i
END
```

Comment: I guess this should work. To make sure it doesn't break, I would probably also use `QUOTENAME()` to delimit every object name used in the dynamic query. Anyway, this doesn't seem to address the actual problem at all. The question was whether moving a condition from a query to the view definition can/will speed up the query or not, **not** *how* to add a condition to a view definition programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a where clause to the view, this will reduce the number of rows you select.
By default sqlserver does not use indexes when you call a view!
To force sqlserver to make use of available indexes, specify "with schemabinding" when you create the view (create view  with schemabinding as …).

Be sure to specifiy an index that can be used by the where spec.